# Is NS2 coding will be helpful in NS3

Tags: network-core

I'm taking Lab on `Modeling and Simulation` this Semester. My instructor is teaching us `NS2`. I searched online and found there is already new version of NS2 called NS3. If I learn NS2 then would it help me in learning NS3 or NS3 is totally a different package. I've read online that it is build from scratch and doesn't support backward compatibility with NS2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, they are quite different. Don't expect code compatibility between the two. Any experience you pick up on network simulations working with NS2 will be applicable to any network simulator so it's not all in vain though ;)